# How to generate proper soap request inside wso2 ESB from Rest call

Tags: soap, wso2, rest-client, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb 4.8.1 and I want to convert my soap web service over esb to Rest service. I have already done that properly with an api way. Successfully I could call the soap service with out passing parameters. But I couldn't send the query parameters which are returned from a REST client to the soap service.

This is my soap service request

[image]

How can I pass the values from rest client to this soap service? I have used payload factory to pass values to soap service inside insequence but it was not success. Can anyone guide me how to do that?

I followed this url, but not succeeded.

Comment: can you add your existing configuration here to see what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this document [1] where it explains how you can convert a SOAP request and send it to a REST backend. Additionally, if you could provide proxy config we will be able to help you with setting it up further. Hope this helps.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-SOAPClientandRESTService

Cheers,
Pubudu.